# Three Table Join with limit on 2 tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I've got a bit of a tricky one here, 3 tables as follows in SQLite:

Cars Table

```
.------.------.--------------.---------.
| vin  | year |     make     |  model  |
'------+------+--------------+---------'
| 1234 | 1965 | Aston Martin | DB5     |
| 5678 | 1965 | Ford         | Mustang |
| 9012 | 1994 | Ford         | Tarus   |
`--------------------------------------'
```

Price Table

```
.------.-------.---------------------.
| vin  | price |    last_modified    |
'------+-------+---------------------'
| 1234 | 60000 | 2012-08-01 12:00:00 |
| 1234 | 58000 | 2012-08-02 12:00:00 |
| 1234 | 56000 | 2012-08-10 12:00:00 |
| 5678 | 30000 | 2012-08-02 12:00:00 |
| 9012 |  1000 | 2012-08-01 12:00:00 |
`------------------------------------'
```

Mileage Table

```
.------.---------.---------------------.
| vin  | mileage |    last_modified    |
'------+---------+---------------------'
| 1234 |   35000 | 2012-08-01 12:00:00 |
| 1234 |   35030 | 2012-08-02 12:00:00 |
| 1234 |   35100 | 2012-08-10 12:00:00 |
| 5678 |   60000 | 2012-08-02 12:00:00 |
| 9012 |  245000 | 2012-08-01 12:00:00 |
`--------------------------------------'
```

I'd like to join all three tables to display all the rows from the "Cars" table, but only bring the single most recent "last_modified" price from the price table and the single highest mileage from the mileage table.

At the end my result would look like:

```
.------.------.--------------.---------.-------.---------.
| vin  | year |     make     |  model  | price | mileage |
'------+------+--------------+---------+-------+---------+
| 1234 | 1965 | Aston Martin | DB5     | 56000 |   35100 |
| 5678 | 1965 | Ford         | Mustang | 30000 |   60000 |
| 9012 | 1994 | Ford         | Tarus   |  1000 |  245000 |
`--------------------------------------------------------'
```

This is what I would do if I were selecting a specific VIN (i.e. "1234"):

```
SELECT
    c.year, c.make, c.model, c.vin, p.price, m.mileage, p.last_modified 
FROM 
    cars c
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                price, vin, last_modified
            FROM 
                price
            WHERE 
                (vin = '1234')
            ORDER BY
                last_modified DESC LIMIT 1
          ) p
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                mileage, vin, last_modified 
            FROM 
                mileage 
            WHERE 
                (vin = '1234') 
            ORDER BY 
                mileage DESC LIMIT 1
           ) m

WHERE
    (c.vin = '1234') AND (c.vin = p.vin) AND (c.vin = m.vin)
GROUP BY
    p.vin, m.vin
ORDER BY 
    c.vin, p.last_modified DESC, m.mileage ASC;
```

...but I'd like to get all the rows from the "Cars" Table.

Anybody have any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get their individual maximum modified date in a `SubQuery`. Try,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.price, c.mileage
FROM    Cars a
            INNER JOIN Price b
                on a.vin = b.vin
            INNER JOIN Mileage c
                on a.vin = c.vin
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT vin, MAX(last_modified) lastMod
                FROM    Price
                GROUP BY vin
            ) d ON  b.vin = d.vin AND
                    b.last_modified = d.lastMod
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT vin, MAX(last_modified) lastMod
                FROM    Mileage
                GROUP BY vin
            ) e ON  c.vin = e.vin AND
                    c.last_modified = e.lastMod
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71705/2)

Comment: This worked for the most part, one small correction with the last subquery:
    INNER JOIN  
    (  
        SELECT vin, MAX(mileage) maxMileage  
        FROM    Mileage  
        GROUP BY vin  
    ) e ON  c.vin = e.vin AND  
            c.mileage = e.maxMileage

Comment: @JohnWoo Kabayan! ツ This first part of your query [SELECT  a.*, b.price, c.mileage FROM Car a INNER JOIN Price b on a.vin = b.vin INNER JOIN Mileage c on a.vin = c.vin](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/71705/7) produces cartesian'd rows. Ex: Ashton Martin has 3 prices and 3 mileage rows, chained joins produces cartesian'd(here it's 9) rows. I don't have big data at hand, I have an inkling that this won't scale well though. Will give you feedback when I tested it later ツ

Comment: @MichaelBuen thanks for your DDL at sqlfiddle. It worked kabayan because even it gives cartesian product on the first join, it was then filtered on the last part of the join `c.vin = e.vin AND
                    c.last_modified = e.lastMod1` and `b.vin = d.vin AND
                    b.last_modified = d.lastMod`

Comment: Yep I know it works kabayan, I mean the intermediate rows(the result of the first two joins, which produces cartesian'd rows, which could become big depending on cartesian product of two tables) for the succeeding joins to join to, could have an impact on performance ツ

Comment: i get your point @MichaelBuen :) , i'll just updated it kabayan. LEt me find another alternative for this..

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/71705/14

```
select c.vin, c.year, c.make, c.model, rpci.price, rmci.mileage 
from car c
join 
(  
  select * from mileage m
  join
  (
    select vin, max(last_modified) recent_modified
    from mileage
    group by vin
  ) rm on rm.vin = m.vin and rm.recent_modified = m.last_modified
) rmci on rmci.vin = c.vin
-- rmci: recent mileage complete info ;-)
join
(
  select * from price p
  join
  (
    select vin, max(last_modified) recent_modified
    from price
    group by vin
  ) rp on rp.vin = p.vin and rp.recent_modified = p.last_modified
) rpci on rpci.vin = c.vin
-- rpci: receint price complete info
```

Output:

```
| c.vin | c.year |       c.make | c.model | rpci.price | rmci.mileage |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1234 |   1965 | Aston Martin |     DB5 |      56000 |        35100 |
|  5678 |   1965 |         Ford | Mustang |      30000 |        60000 |
|  9012 |   1994 |         Ford |   Tarus |       1000 |       245000 |
```

Query progression here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/71705/14

Answer (score 0):

You could use correlated queries in the select list. It's ugly, but it would work. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery